# PHP lint won't display detailed error message even with display_errors=1

Tags: php, debugging

There are a number of other questions on SO about how to get line numbers and error messages with PHP's built-in linter. I've read them and tried their suggestions with no effect. This may be a bug, but I thought I'd ask before filing a bug report on the PHP project.

I have `display_errors` set to `On` in `/etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini` on an Ubuntu 18.04 system. I also am overriding the setting with my command line argument:

```
php -d display_errors=1 -l file_with_obvious_syntax_error.php
```

I get:

```
Errors parsing file_with_obvious_syntax_error.php
```

But no line numbers or any indication of what the error is.

```
#php -v  // edited out built time in output
PHP 7.4.6 (cli) ( NTS )
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
  with Zend OPcache v7.4.6, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

I've set `opcache.enable_cli=0` in `/etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini` and confirmed (from `php --ini`) that is the config file the cli client is using. I've also redirected `stderr` to `stdout` and there's no add'l info.

Comment: Do you have `error_reporting = E_ALL`

Comment: Thank you. I had `error_reporting = E_COMPILE_ERROR|E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR|E_ERROR|E_CORE_ERROR`. I never would have guessed that enabling reporting for compile errors would result in... compile errors not being reported.

Answer (score 0):

@AbraCadaver provided the answer in a comment. I'm answering the question in case someone else comes across this, because the behaviour is not intuitive. I had error reporting set to report compile errors:

`error_reporting = E_COMPILE_ERROR|E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR|E_ERROR|E_CORE_ERROR`

which apparently does *not* cause PHP to report compile errors. Setting the value to `E_ALL` corrected the problem.